# Shape Count vs. Record Count Mismatch

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, arcgis-10.5

*First of all, I really could not think of a good title for this question, so feel free to modify it.*

I keep encountering an error using ArcMap 10.5.1. I'll have a table open, to which I add a field.

Here is a table to which I added the fields "x" and "y" for the x and y coordinates:

[image]

Then when I attempt to "Calculate Geometry" for either of these new fields, I get the following sequence of error messages:

[image]

[image]

I also tried to use the "Add Surface Information" tool in 3D Analyst, and it gives me the following error messages:

[image]

I also tried adding a field to a polygon shapefile and then adding surface information. It gave me the following error message, which may actually point to the source of the problem. It appears to be a mismatch between the number of shapes vs the number of records. I have no idea why, since the attribute table appears to look correct:

[image]

One curious thing is that the shapefiles appear to be corrupted after this occurs. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify what you are calculating exactly? How can you calculate the geometry of the X or Y columns? Are you trying to get the coordinates of X and Y? I don’t think you should bother with 3D tools, which are of no use in this situation because you are only working with X and Y. I can imagine your shapefiles will corrupt after performing the ‘add surface Information’.

Comment: Try this, select the rows in your shapefile then run it through copy features to create a new dataset, then do your processing on that copy.

Comment: @Jelle To clarify, the x and y values using Calculate Geometry that I was after were for the coordinates of each point. I also wanted some elevation values for each point, which was attempting to append to the table using the Add Surface Information tool. I was also attempting to obtain an average slope and average elevation for a polygon shapefile in the last example of Add Surface Information. In both cases, I had added a field prior to running Calculate Geometry or Add Surface Information. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: @Hornbydd I have been attempting to export the dataset to a new file. Each function will work the first time, but once I save and try running additional tools on those exported files, I end up with the same error.

Comment: Try running the Check Geometry tool.  If it returns with errors, fix them with the Repair Geometry tool.

Comment: Where are you datasets stored? Not in some dropbox folder which is trying to sync and corrupting the datasets?

Comment: @Hornbydd  All of my data are stored on a network drive, and I am running ArcMap through an Oracle enterprise system (Citrix). All I know is it's frustrating. I can't even overwrite the corrupted files with new ones. I have to locate the files on the network drive. Seems like this issue is going to be a fact of life.